# Does the transliteration of 'Dravidian' exist in Hindu scripture? Does 'Dravida' refer to a Geographical area or an ethnic group?

Tags: history

I read somewhere that the religious texts do not have any mention of referring to some people as 'Dravidians'. There is rife debate on whether the people in the Dravid were the original inhabitants, who had been forced to move southward by the Central Asian Aryan settlers.

So, I would like to know if the texts have any mention of referring to people of the south as 'Dravidians' (may or may not be presumed inferior).

Comment: question does not relate to hindu religion....

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Its a sanskrit word with the following meanings

> द्राविडः [द्रविडदेशो$भिजनो$स्य-अण्] 1 A Dravidian, Dravida. -2 A general name for a Brāhmaṇa of any of the five southern tribes (the पञ्चद्रविड);

In Skanda-Purana, the word 'Dravida' is mentioned to imply one of the five types of residents of the Southern side of the Vindhya Mountains :

> कर्णाटाश्चैव तैलङ्गा गुर्जरा राष्ट्रवासिनः । आन्ध्राश्च द्राविडा पञ्च विन्ध्यदक्षिणवासिनः ॥ karnAtas cha eva tailangA gurjarA rAshtravAsinah/ AndhrAsh cha drAvidA pancha vindhya-dakshina-vAsinah//

Reference : https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A1&lang=sans&action=Search

Comment: Does the use of 'Dravida' have a derogatory aspect anywhere? Also, is 'mlechha' used to refer to them?

Comment: @AabeshGhosh I do not think its derogatory.But its believed that Agastya took Vedas to the Southern part of India. No, I dont think they were called mlechchas so far as my limited knowledge goes.